# CommerceJS is extremely slow

Tags: e-commerce

I am on the free plan of commerce JS and building a test shop here https://laisttier.vercel.app

If I use Postman to run the request I'm running in the site I can see the slowness is coming from [CommerceJS](https://commercejs.com/). It takes 10-60 seconds to load a category page.

Here is my request:
https://api.chec.io/v1/products?sortBy=created&sortOrder=desc&page=1&limit=3&category_slug=oil-paintings

headers
X-Authorization = pk_test_51151e094d4eb944afab836227fc541e1893399e643db